What's with the rat and the bride in Gabriela Mistral's La rata?
In the first stanza of Gabriela Mistral's poem La rata animals run after other animals in a way that defies expectations. In the remaining stanzas, the speaker addresses someone else, telling him or her to chase after the animals and finally, in the last stanza, to climb up and run after the bride. The climbing in the last stanza seems to be opposed to the movement in the first stanza, where the direction is towards the sea.
What is going on here? What is the connection between the animals and the addressee? Why would a rat run after (or chase?) a deer, and a deer a jaguar, etcetera? What is the purpose or meaning of catching the rat, the deer, the buffalo and the sea? What is the meaning of the thread in the rat's paws? (It's a woollen thread, but sheep aren't mentioned in the poem.) Is the bride in the last stanza the speaker of the poem, since the third stanza refers to a wedding gown she will wear?

Below is a fairly literal English translation of the poem:

A rat ran to/after a deer
and the deers to/after the jaguar,
and the jaguars to/after the buffaloes,
and the buffaloes to the sea...
Catch, catch the ones that are leaving!
Catch the rat, catch the deer!
catch the buffaloes and the sea!
See that the rat at the front / Look, the rat in front
is carrying embroidery wool in its paws,
and with the wool I embroider my dress,
and with the dress I'm going to marry.
Go up and cross the plain,
Run breathlessly, go on without stopping.
Fly for the bride, and for the bridal party,
And for the carriage and the bridal veil.


I have a personal interpretation and except for sources that say she like animals very much, I don't I can find any authority on this. I'd interpret those animals as "noble" whereas a rat is not. However, the rat is clever and it trips up those noble creatures. Also, rata in Spanish can mean cowardly or miserly. So, here's the poor little, clever rat who gets the wool (from unseen sheep or llamas) provides wool for the bride's dress. The bride "wears" the wool from the rat and is associated with it while the other animals fly around the bride and her accountrements, in a kind of aerial ballet.

It's really an allegory. So, the rat's legacy is close to her but the others only fly around her and her wedding party. For me, the suggestion is that she is miserly but in the company of creatures more noble than she...

Maybe the rat is running away with the embroidery wool for the wedding dress, and they have to catch her so the speaker can get married.
